# display UIAlert when apps running on background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"open app" message:@" backgr..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alertView show];
```

How could I display alert when apps running background?

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) when your app is in the background.

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.alertBody = @"Your message";
notification.alertAction = @"Open app";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

Comment: How would I know? It's your project, not mine.

Comment: Thanks DrummerB. But I want to show alert only. Not a local notification. Is it possible. Please share your view about this. Waiting for reply.

Comment: You can't show an alert when your app is in the background. Your only choice is a `UILocalNotification`.

Comment: thanks again DrummerB. Actually my target is to launch one apps from background. Means when apps running on background will launch other apps. Is it Possible in IOS. please share your view.