# Objective-C: Is it possible to display a alert while app is inactive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I saw a screen from a app in App Store that displays a `Alert` even when the app is inactive. Is it possible to do it?

If yes, Please help.

Comment: not that i know of... but then again ive never tried. which app does this?

Comment: This, see the fifth screen shot:
https://appsto.re/us/nTE3D.i

Comment: it seems only possible if you display a local notification and the user has chosen to show notifications as alerts in their settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702730/display-uialert-when-apps-running-on-background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445219/show-alert-on-sceen-when-app-is-in-background

Comment: Yea thats right, thanks!